# Regarding Opencart 1.5.6.2 Slideshow Banner Image code understanding in the database

Tags: opencart

How to understand the value of the key of table oc_setting in the opencart database, ie., slideshow banner image code which is like

```
a:2:
{

i:0;
a:5:{
s:4:"file";
s:20:"data/Aadi-Banner.png";
s:3:"url";
s:0:"";
s:3:"alt";
s:0:"";
s:6:"target";
s:5:"_self";
s:9:"sortorder";
s:0:"";
}
}
```

Can anyone please help me in figuring out that task...

Answer (score 1):

That is a serialized value stored in the database. Take a look at http://php.net/unserialize for how to get this back to an array. If you are loading this via OpenCart, it should already unserialize it for you when you access it through `$this->config->get('banner_item_name_here');`